# Appending content from .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.content').load('http://example.com/page/2/ .content .post');
```

It gets all the content from that page, and replaces whatever *was* in `$('.content')`, with the new stuff.

However, I don't want it to replace it, I want it to *append* to it.

I've tried:

```
$('.content').append($('.content').load('http://example.com/page/2/ .content .post'));
```

But it still replaces the content, it does not add to it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've seen `load()` overwrites any content already in the element. If you want to append to existing content you need to roll your own AJAX request and use `append()`:

```
$.get('http://example.com/page/2', function(html) {
    $('.content').append($('.content .post', html));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that get all the content from the next page, or is it only getting `.content .post` ?

Comment: The AJAX request gets all of the content, the append is restricted to just the `.content .post` elements though.

Comment: Aah okay. Is there a way to load only certain parts of the next page, or is this infact what `.load('http://example.com/page/2/ .content .post');` does anyway?

Comment: This is what load() is doing for you under the hood. There is no in between with an AJAX request - it gets all data or nothing.

Comment: @tmyie From the `.load` doc : *"If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a **jQuery selector** that determines the content to be loaded."* Same as Rory's code.